# Question about separation the limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$a_n=\frac{1000^{\sqrt[100]{n}}}{(1,01)^n}+n^{1000}(0,99)^{\sqrt[100]{n}}$

Is it correct to write that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty\ }a_n=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty\ } \frac{1000^{\sqrt[100]{n}}}{(1,01)^n} + \lim \limits_{n \to \infty\ } n^{1000}(0,99)^{\sqrt[100]{n}}=...=0+0=0$?

Comment: Yes its ok provided you also show how the limit of those two terms is $0$. It may not appear obvious/self-evident to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit function is a linear function, so yes, it's okay and acceptable. You have to show explicitly how the limit of the two terms is $0$ though, to make sure you have a rigorous approach.

Comment: Thank you. I got it from $a=e^{loga}$, and arithmetic properties of logarithm, and $e^{-\infty}=0$

Comment: @matematiccc Glad I could help ! If you consider that this answered your question you can accept it by clicking at the tick button below the vote buttons !